# Trying to display an Photo when button is clicked ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner. I'm trying to make a button upon clicking shows an image. I already imported the photo from the public folder:
import Photo from '../../public/images/myPhoto.jpg';
what do i do now.

Comment: Please share some code to support your question.

Comment: you can try and try and learn from trying ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 import yourImage from "../images/yourImage"; 
   
 const [show , setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleOnClick = () => {
    setShow(true);
    }
    
    
    <button onClick={handleOnClick}></button>
    {
        show && <img src={yourImage} alt="abc" />
    }
```

I have attach simple example please check [click here](https://codepen.io/Zeeshan-Akram/pen/qBPQpGN)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Photo from '../public/images/yourPhoto.jpg';
const DisplayImageComponent = () => {
  const [isImageActive, setIsImageActive] = useState(false);
  function clickEventHandler() {
    setIsImageActive(true);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickEventHandler}>Activate image</button>
      {isImageActive && <img src={Photo} alt="your image name " />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DisplayImageComponent;
```

//[1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bagc2h?file=src%2FApp.js